# Скрыть div при воспроизведении youtube видео и показать при паузе

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

```css
.liner-line {
  left: 7px;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.boxs .box-liner .box {
  left: 3px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 294px;
  height: 163px;
  padding: 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 14px 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #efeff0;
  transition: box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
}

.div_to_be_hidden {
  z-index: 3;
  top: 127px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 293px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(45, 0, 255, 0.56);
}

.liner {
  height: 185px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.font {
  left: 230px;
  z-index: 8;
  width: 52px;
  bottom: 26px;
  height: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(241, 239, 239, 0.2);
}

.liner-next {
  z-index: 8;
  right: -4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-position: 0 0px;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.liner .font .liner-prev.disable {
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: default;
}

.liner .font .liner-prev {
  z-index: 8;
  right: 9px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-position: 0 0px;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.liner .font .liner-next {
  top: 7px;
  right: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 16px;
  height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.liner .font .liner-prev {
  top: 7px;
  right: 31px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 16px;
  height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.news_span {
  top: 7px;
  left: 24px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  font: 14px/16px 'Roboto-Regular', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="liner">
  <div class="font">
    <span class="mad liner-next"></span>
    <span class="liner-prev disable"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="liner-line">
    <div class="box blocks" data-id="1">
      <div class="div_to_be_hidden">
        <span class="news_span"> Выпуск 1</span>
      </div>
      <iframe width="294" height="163" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QuIwUTO0H7M?showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""> </iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос такой,как, когда пользователь нажимает воспроизвести видео блок `div_to_be_hidden` нужно скрыть, при паузе - снова показать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('maVideo', {
          height: '163',
          width: '294',
          videoId: 'QuIwUTO0H7M',
          events: {
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if(player.getPlayerState() == 3 || player.getPlayerState() == 1) {
                console.log("hide div");
                $('.div_to_be_hidden').hide();
            }

            if(player.getPlayerState() == 0 || player.getPlayerState() == 2) { 
              console.log("return div");
              $('.div_to_be_hidden').show();
            }
      }
```

```css
.liner-line {
  left: 7px;
  position: relative;
  transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.boxs .box-liner .box {
  left: 3px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 294px;
  height: 163px;
  padding: 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 14px 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #efeff0;
  transition: box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: -ms-box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-box-shadow .3s ease-in-out;
}

.div_to_be_hidden {
  z-index: 3;
  top: 127px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 293px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(45, 0, 255, 0.56);
}

.liner {
  height: 185px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.font {
  left: 230px;
  z-index: 8;
  width: 52px;
  bottom: 26px;
  height: 27px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(241, 239, 239, 0.2);
}

.liner-next {
  z-index: 8;
  right: -4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-position: 0 0px;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.liner .font .liner-prev.disable {
  opacity: 0.3;
  cursor: default;
}

.liner .font .liner-prev {
  z-index: 8;
  right: 9px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-position: 0 0px;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.liner .font .liner-next {
  top: 7px;
  right: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 16px;
  height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.liner .font .liner-prev {
  top: 7px;
  right: 31px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 16px;
  height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.news_span {
  top: 7px;
  left: 24px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  font: 14px/16px 'Roboto-Regular', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="liner">
  <div class="font">
    <span class="mad liner-next"></span>
    <span class="liner-prev disable"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="liner-line">
    <div class="box blocks" data-id="1">
      <div class="div_to_be_hidden">
        <span class="news_span"> Выпуск 1</span>
      </div>
      <div id="maVideo">
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Всего лишь достаточно прочитать [документацию по API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status), вот пример вашего вопроса:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqpPNG)

Comment: Спасибо, значит невнимательно читал.